# Questionable iconv-lite dependency

Tags: angular, webpack, iconv

Been working in an Angular project a couple of months with a very large bundle size, I've been trying to minimize the main bundle and lazy loading some routes. Using `webpack-bundle-analyzer` I've seen that a very large part of the bundle (g-zipped) is a package called `iconv-lite` that exists under `encoding` and I can't find what part of the app is using it.

Is it angular that is using it? Does anyone have an idea? I can see some things have dependencies to it in my `yarn.lock` like `jest` and `less` but those shouldn't be included in the main bundle.

Happy to get into some direction here.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of investigation, we found that it was a dependency called `gettext-parser` that was issue. `gettext-parser` was not meant for browsers. Webpack polyfilled the required node.js modules and one of them was `body-parser` and then in turn `iconv-lite`.

We found this by updating to Angular 12 when `webpack@5` stopped polyfilling node.js dependencies and it started to throw errors during the build.